# Bootstrap Carousel Fade and Buttons items not working

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to test out creating a carousel on bootstrap that fades between three images (in this case 3 'gorilla' jpgs). But I am having difficulties as I learn HTML.

Issue 1: The carousel is not fading between these images despite the class being set to "carousel slide carousel-fade".

Issue 2: The button classes at the bottom are displaying the text Previous and Next and are working, however, I am needing these to be icons rather than text. Hiding the text does not display the icons.

I am a beginner at all of this so I appreciate all the help!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
  
</head>

<body>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true"
        aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="3000">
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/150x150.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="3000">
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/50x50.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="3000">
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/100x100.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4 needs jquery. So you need to add jquery to your site.

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add additional CSS to get the fade to work the way you want.

This doesn't show very well in StackOverflow's code snippet preview so you may have better luck looking at [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/km0ser/pen/GRrjzdX).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <style>
    .carousel.carousel-fade .carousel-item {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity ease-out .7s;
    }

    .carousel.carousel-fade .carousel-item.active {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity ease-out .7s;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true"
        aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="3000">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x300?a" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="3000">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x300?b" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="3000">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x300?c" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```